# Make date out of year and repetitive sequence of 1827 days

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I started with a dataframe that had hours and a sequence of days from 1-1827 (5 years). I know that day 1 is 2004-01-01. I added days. I'm out of ideas on how to move on to make this a date (so I can match it up with other data).

Here's how it looks so far:

```
hour<-rep(0:24, 1828)
day_of_seq<-rep(0:1827, 25)

library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(hour, day_of_seq)%>%
 mutate(year = ifelse((day_of_seq > 0 & day_of_seq <= 366), 2004,
               ifelse((day_of_seq >= 337 & day_of_seq <= 731), 2005,
               ifelse((day_of_seq >= 732 & day_of_seq <= 1096), 2006,
               ifelse((day_of_seq >= 1097 & day_of_seq <= 1461), 2007,
               ifelse((day_of_seq >= 1462 & day_of_seq <= 1827), 2008, "nope"))))))
```

Comment: `as.Date('2004-01-01') + 0:1827` will do the trick because adding 1 to a Date object means add 1 day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
data.table(hour, as.Date(day_seq, origin = "2004-01-01"))
```

Comment: Worked great for the example. For my real data, wouldn't recognize the column name for some reason and I had to use `df$day_seq` instead of just `day_seq`.

Answer (score 1):

with base R:

```
seq(from=as.Date("2004-01-01"), length.out = 1827, by="1 days")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the OP wants to create a series of hourly timestamps over 5 years time which should be displayed in two columns as date (class `Date`) and hour of the day (integer).

OP's approach is to create a cross product of hours of the day and days.

IMHO, there is a much simpler approach which uses the `seq()` method for date-time classes:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
DT <- data.table(time = seq(ymd_h("2004-01-01 00"), 
                            ymd_h("2008-01-01 00"), by = "1 hour"))
DT
```

> ```
>                       time
>     1: 2004-01-01 00:00:00
>     2: 2004-01-01 01:00:00
>     3: 2004-01-01 02:00:00
>     4: 2004-01-01 03:00:00
>     5: 2004-01-01 04:00:00
>    ---                    
> 43845: 2008-12-31 20:00:00
> 43846: 2008-12-31 21:00:00
> 43847: 2008-12-31 22:00:00
> 43848: 2008-12-31 23:00:00
> 43849: 2009-01-01 00:00:00
> ```

Now, we can create the `date` and `hour` columns:

```
DT[, date := as.Date(time)][, hour := hour(time)][]
```

> ```
>                       time       date hour
>     1: 2004-01-01 00:00:00 2004-01-01    0
>     2: 2004-01-01 01:00:00 2004-01-01    1
>     3: 2004-01-01 02:00:00 2004-01-01    2
>     4: 2004-01-01 03:00:00 2004-01-01    3
>     5: 2004-01-01 04:00:00 2004-01-01    4
>    ---                                    
> 43845: 2008-12-31 20:00:00 2008-12-31   20
> 43846: 2008-12-31 21:00:00 2008-12-31   21
> 43847: 2008-12-31 22:00:00 2008-12-31   22
> 43848: 2008-12-31 23:00:00 2008-12-31   23
> 43849: 2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-01    0
> ```

#### Caveat

OP's approach creates nearly 2000 more rows

```
str(df)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 45700 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ hour      : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
>  $ day_of_seq: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
>  $ year      : chr  "nope" "2004" "2004" "2004" ...
> ```

than my approach:

```
str(DT)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    43849 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ time: POSIXct, format: "2004-01-01 00:00:00" "2004-01-01 01:00:00" "2004-01-01 02:00:00" ...
>  $ date: Date, format: "2004-01-01" "2004-01-01" "2004-01-01" ...
>  $ hour: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

This is caused by OP's numbering the hours of the day by `0:24` which means that each midnight appears twice, as 2400 hours of the actual date and as 0000 hours of the subsequent date.

This might be intended by the OP but normally `2004-01-01 24:00:00` is considered to denote the same instance in time as `2004-01-02 00:00:00`.